# Server 2003 IIS Error

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

All day we have been getting interment IIS errors - we reboot and it fixes the issue a short time. In the error logs we are getting

**A process serving application pool  exceeded time limits during shut down. The process id was '2260'.**

Our app seems to die in chunks so it will not stall competely --> but certain sections will broke with this error -->

**Cannot execute a program. The command being executed was "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths @"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\lms\6ae61309\7e6c5096\jywwvsao.cmdline".**

NEXT you will get a "Document cannot be created" error when trying to start error log ect ect over RDP - the server still work but IIS stops working completely--> I will try to restart the service but get an error saying: **Bad Image Please check this against your installation diskette** OR  "**The application failed to initialize properly**" something along those lines.

The disk had mirror raid set up, iis 6

ANY ideas are most welcome

Answer (score 2):

> This problem might occur because
>   ASP.NET limits the number of worker
>   threads and completion port threads
>   that a call can use to execute
>   requests.
>
> Typically, a call to a Web service
>   uses one worker thread to execute the
>   code that sends the request and one
>   completion port thread to receive the
>   callback from the Web service.
>   However, if the request is redirected
>   or requires authentication, the call
>   may use as many as two worker and two
>   completion port threads. Therefore,
>   you can exhaust the managed ThreadPool
>   when multiple Web service calls occur
>   at the same time.
>
> For example, suppose that the
>   ThreadPool is limited to 10 worker
>   threads, and all 10 worker threads are
>   currently executing code that is
>   waiting for a callback to execute. The
>   callback can never execute because any
>   work items that are queued to the
>   ThreadPool are blocked until a thread
>   becomes available.
>
> Another potential source of contention
>   is the maxconnection parameter that
>   the System.Net namespace uses to limit
>   the number of connections. Generally,
>   this limit works as expected. However,
>   if many applications try to make many
>   requests to a single IP address at the
>   same time, threads may have to wait
>   for an available connection.
>   To resolve these problems, you can
>   tune the following parameters in your
>   Machine.config file to best fit your
>   situation:
>
> ```
> * maxWorkerThreads
> * minWorkerThreads
> * maxIoThreads
> * minFreeThreads
> * minLocalRequestFreeThreads
> * maxconnection
> * executionTimeout
> ```
>
> To successfully resolve these
>   problems, do the following...

The quote's continued [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268)... If that doesn't work, you can dig deeper with what's explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919792).

Answer (score 2):

I would check the Windows event log for other errors. From the errors you report, it seems that ASP.NET cannot compile the aspx/ascx files into temporary assemblies.

It could be a hardware/RAID/filesystem problem which makes the C# compiler (csc.exe) fail.